# Notation of the summation of a set of numbers

Tags: summation, notation

Given a set of numbers $S=\{x_1,\dotsc,x_{|S|}\}$, where $|S|$ is the size of the set, what would be the appropriate notation for the sum of this set of numbers? Is it

$$\sum_{x_i \in S} x_i
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\sum_{i=1}^{|S|} x_i$$ or something else?

Comment: Knuth's Concrete Mathematics p. 22 discusses this, and has a whole chapter about the summation operator.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'd write either $\displaystyle\quad\sum_{i=1}^{|S|} x_i\quad$ or $\displaystyle\quad\sum_{x\in S} x$.

If the second form is used, then the subscript is just clutter.

Some mathematicians (perhaps especially set theorists?) might write $\displaystyle \sum S$.  This would parallel the way set theorists write $\displaystyle \bigcup S$ where others might write $\displaystyle \bigcup_{x\in S} x$.

Comment: The set theorist's notation is useful, because it does not invoke dummy variables. The idea is that $\sum$ should be a function of type $\mathscr{P} \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (or replace $\mathbb{R}$ with your favourite ring). This idea eventually leads to the general notion higher-order functions and functors and monads...

Comment: What does $x_i$ mean, considering that a set doesn't have any order (and hence not any "$i$th" element)?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye : Often one specifies the members of a set by means of a sequence or other indexed family. For example $\left\{\frac 1 i : i\in\mathbb N\right\}.$ That doesn't mean that that way of putting the members of the set in one-to-one correspondence with the members of $\mathbb N$ is an attribute of the set itself. $\qquad$

Comment: That makes sense. But is this a more colloquial way of writing or is it generally accepted also in formal contexts?

Comment: When it comes to your example, though, I don't really understand what you are trying to illustrate, as that expression works even without sequencing the natural numbers (i.e. it doesn't require the natural numbers to have any specific order).

Comment: @HelloGoodbye : "Sequencing" here would just mean putting into one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb N. \qquad$

Comment: Hm, maybe I misinterpreted you. What if the members of the set are _not_ specified by means of a sequence or other indexed family? In the general case, I guess they are not. So only in special cases you could use the first notation with the indexed elements, right?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye : Yes. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5):

Both expressions are acceptable with the second being more usual in this context.

The expression $$\sum_{x \in S} x$$ is more common when $S$ is implicitly defined, e.g., when one is summing over all prime numbers. The expression $$\sum_{i =1}^{|S|} x_i$$ would be more common here because you are explicitly given the list of elements of the set $S$.

Comment: As Michael Hardy says below, the subscripts are unnecessary and unsightly in the first expression.

Answer (score -1):

Say I had a set A, under an operation with the properties of $+$, then $$\sum_{i\in A} x_i$$ is how I write it.

Comment: You'd be summing undefined items

Comment: You want to write $i \in \{1,\dots,|A|\}$ instead of $i \in A$ since $i$ is an index. It doesn't make any sense to use an element in $A$ to index $x$ (which is what you are currently doing since you write $i \in A$).