# Sigma notation for iterating through number of members of a set with constant expression

Tags: graph-theory, summation, proof-writing, notation

Say I have a graph G and I want to sum some constant C (like the minimum degree of the graph) for every vertex. Can I use the following notation? 
$$\sum_{x \in V(G)}C $$

Is this an appropriate way to use sigma notation?
There is a similar question here [Notation of the summation of a set of numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111724/notation-of-the-summation-of-a-set-of-numbers)
but it doesn't account for the fact that the expression could be a constant. A person I am working with questioned it and I couldn't find any resources where it is used in this manner. I don't see why it would be improper because you could have an expression like $\sum_{i=1}^{n}C$.
Thank you

Comment: It looks logically correct, but why wouldn't you just write $\lvert V(G)\rvert \cdot C$?

Comment: We do at some point in our proof. We actually use this notation and the equation that  @gt6989b posted.

Comment: OK, I could imagine your notation as an intermediate step while simplifying some other sum where you can separate out a constant term. Some authors would skip that intermediate step and go straight to the the multiplication but I think that is something you can decide not do to if you think it's helpful to show the intermediate step explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you are correct, you can use $\sum_{x \in S} C$ for any set $S$ and constant $C$, and since $C$ does not depend on $x$, this simplifies to
$$
\sum_{x \in S} C = C \cdot |S|,
$$
for any *finite* set $S$.